# Need to apply same left alignment to multiple line text

Tags: css

Simple question for CSS experts:

Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU4U/

The text is currently appearing like this:

```
* Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum:
```

I need to make it look like this, by only changing the CSS being used:

```
* Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum:
```

How can I do that ?

**EDIT:**

If really needed, the HTML code can also be changed.

But I cannot use `.required` CSS rule, because that is already being used elsewhere, and if I change that, it will cause other problems ..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/TFU4U/1/

Comment: I am struggling with this too. Just can't figure out how to do it. It's the only css element I don't understand >.< Kinda silly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TFU4U/2/ (no need for margin-left)

Comment: I cannot use .required because its already being used, and if I change that, it will disturb other elements ..

Comment: @Ahmad: @CBroe has already give you the answer above. If you cannot use `required` as the class name for the `<span class='required">*</span>`, then simply change the class name to something else.

Comment: CBroe, I've accepted your answer mate .. If you can make a formal answer for that, I'll accept it .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to your paragraphes and position your spans absolutely. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aDfWy/).

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="x">
    <span>*</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="x">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.x span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.x p {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `li` element to achieve this? It does what you are after...

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/29w5F/)

**CSS**

```
.option-l li {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.option-r {
    margin-left: 60%;
}
```

**HTML**
Remove the `span` and just use `li`

```
<div class="option-l">
    <ul><li><b>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum:</b></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thing is, I have to use the * sign, and not bullets .. :/

Comment: @CBroe has already give you the answer above. If you cannot use required as the class name for the `<span class='required">*</span>`, then simply change the class name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<p id="test"><span>*</span>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#test span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```